# Regex match space not \n

Tags: sublimetext2

Original text is

```
81277184956 0 31    10000    0    0  0  0  4
afdsf sadfdsf
```

I want to replace all space with character "|" by regex at Sublime text 2.

Expected result should be

```
81277184956|0|31|10000|0|0|0|0|4
afdsf|sadfdsf
```

If i use pattern "\s+", it will match \n too so that two lines change to one line. How to get correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[:blank:]]+`, which equals to `[\x20\t]+`

Click [here](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) for more details of Oniguruma Regular Expression syntax, regex module used in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an exclusion "^".

```
\s+[^\n]
```

Answer (score 0):

> `regex=re.compile(' ') a=regex.sub('|',a)`

This is how you can easily get the thing done.