# Python regex match space only

Tags: python, regex

In python3, how do I match exactly whitespace character and not newline \n or tab \t?

I've seen the `\s+[^\n]` answer from   [Regex match space not \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190038/regex-match-space-not-n) answer, but for the following example it does not work:

```
a='rasd\nsa sd'
print(re.search(r'\s+[^ \n]',a))
```

Result is `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 6), match='\ns'>`, which is the newline matched.

Comment: BTW, the `r'\s+[^ \n]'` you have supplied was not even an accepted answer and Python `re` does not support POSIX character classes like `[[:blank:]]`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

No need for special groups. Just create a regex with a space character. The space character does not have any special meaning, it just means "match a space".

```
RE = re.compile(' +')
```

So for your case

```
a='rasd\nsa sd'
print(re.search(' +', a))
```

would give

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 8), match=' '>
```

Comment: Yes, this turns out to be the case, I've just expected it to have independent escape sequence, like other whitespaces do.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to match 1 or more whitespace chars except the newline and a tab use

```
r"[^\S\n\t]+"
```

The `[^\S]` matches any char that is not a non-whitespace = any char that is whitespace. However, since the character class is a negated one, when you add characters to it they are excluded from matching.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/qypvmj):

```
import re
a='rasd\nsa sd'
print(re.findall(r'[^\S\n\t]+',a))
# => [' ']
```

Some more considerations: [`\s` matches `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) if ASCII flag is used. So, if you plan to only match ASCII, you might as well use `[ \r\f\v]` to exclude the chars you want. If you need to work with Unicode strings, the solution above is a viable one.