# Python Regular Expression to match space but not newline

Tags: python, regex, newline

I have a string like so:

```
'\n479 Appendix I\n1114\nAppendix I 481\n'
```

and want to use a regular expression to find and return

```
['479 Appendix I', 'Appendix I 481']
```

I first tried this expression:

```
pattern = r'''
(?: \d+ \s)? Appendix \s+ \w+ (?: \s \d+)?
'''

regex = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)

regex.findall(s)
```

But this returns

```
['479 Appendix I\n1114', 'Appendix I 481']
```

because `\s` also matches `\n`. 
  Following one of the answers in this post [Python regex match space only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162444/python-regex-match-space-only), 
I tried the following:

```
pattern = r'''
(?: \d+ [^ \S\t\n])? Appendix \s+ \w+ (?: [^ \S\t\n] \d+)?
'''

regex = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)

regex.findall(s)
```

which however didn't return the desired result, giving:

```
['Appendix I', 'Appendix I']
```

What expression would work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex is a bit more robust than the one in the other answer because it explicitly anchors at "Appendix":

```
pattern = '(?:\d*[\t ]+)?Appendix\s+\w+(?:[\t ]+\d*)?'
re.findall(pattern, s)
#['479 Appendix I', 'Appendix I 481']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s = '\n479 Appendix I\n1114\nAppendix I 481\n'

for g in re.findall(r'^.*[^\d\n].*$', s, flags=re.M):
    print(g)
```

Prints:

```
479 Appendix I
Appendix I 481
```

This regex will match all lines that contain at least one character different than digit or newline. Explanation of [this regex here](https://regex101.com/r/viYR19/2).

Comment: This answers the question but in practice I need to search for all the "Appendix I" in a book, so there is a lot of paragraphs, etc. between two adjacent "Appendix I"s, in which case this answer doesn't really work.