# What does '\t' match to in python regular expression objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading through a previous answer to a stackoverflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38162461/11783775), where the '\t' regular expression code was mentioned, i.e. something that matches a tab. For my own curiousity, I wanted to make a regular expression object to see what exactly '\t' matches, i.e. how many spaces, but I have found nothing on my own.

Here is the regex object:

```py
tabTesterRegex = re.compile(r'''
    (\t)
''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Here is some of the text I was testing with (the bottom line represents a keyboard tab space between 'a' and 'b'.)

```py
text = '''
a b
a  b
a   b
a    b
a     b
a      b
a       b
a        b
a         b
a          b
a           b
a            b
a             b
a              b
a               b
a                b
a   b
'''
```

Here is the code for finding matches and appending them to a list.

```py
matchList = []
for match in tabTesterRegex.findall(text):
    matchList.append(match)

print(matchList)
```

The output that I recieve is an empty list, but I would have assumed that '\t' would match to a specific number of spaces.

Thank you

Comment: I think your editor converted your tab at the bottom to spaces. When I replaced it with a tab character, I got `['\t']` as a return.

Comment: Ah yes definitely. I did the same and it worked now! Thank you

Comment: `\t` or Tab isn't a shortcut for multiple spaces, it's an ASCII character,  just like `\n` (Return), "a" or "1" are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\t` is for matching `tabs`, which are different from spaces. If you append a\t\t\tb, you will get:

```
a b
a  b
a   b
a    b
a     b
a      b
a       b
a        b
a         b
a          b
a           b
a            b
a             b
a              b
a               b
a                b
a           b
```

Note that the spacing may vary depending on your IDE's settings. I may be erroneously assuming you're using spaces based on your first few output lines as they don't equate to the length of a tab, but as PyNoob's comment suggests your editor may be converting tabs.